# How to search for line that contain letter "foo" above the line

Tags: regex, vim

In vim how to search for line that contain letter "foo" above the line.

Example file snippet:

```
class A {
    int a;
}  

class B {
     int a;
}

     // something else with 5 spaces
```

In this example I want to be able to search for class B since it followed by exactly 5 spaces in next line but do not my search to find `Class A` or the comment with 5 spaces.

Comment: why don't you just search "foo" and go down one line?

Comment: Because in this case it is 1 line down, in some other cases it may be 100 to 1000 lines down.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit: Perhaps this is just confusion on my part, but your question isn't very clear. If you just want to search or find the line that has "foo" above it, isn't it equivalent to searching for "foo" and going one line below it?  Granted some corner cases are when "foo" is in the last line of the file or the paragraph, but I don't understand the 100 line argument...

Comment: this questions belongs on SuperUser and there is a good reason why SO don't accept short question. In your case, you can easily add useful information. For example stating your exact goal, rephrase the question to avoid the first comment, add an example, etc

Comment: @Talespin_Kit: One alternate understanding of your question (although not clear from it the way it reads now) is that there are lines that contain "foo" and you want to search _only within_ every line directly below these lines. For e.g., if lines 1,100 have "foo" in them, lines 2,4 have "bar" and lines 50,101 have "baz" in them, you're asking if there is a way you can only search for "bar" in line 2, given the knowledge that line 1 has "foo"

Comment: I have a python file which contains several classes in it, and also the most of the code in the python file is formatted according to the pep8 standard. i.e 4 spaces instead of tabs, but some of the classes contain 5 spaces i want to find those classes, so i want to find the line containing 5 spaces and also there should be the word class above the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but may be this search will work for you in vim:

```
/^\s*class.*\n^\s\{5}
```

That will search for keyword class in one line followed by exact 5 spaces in next line.

Comment: thanks very much, If possible reformat my question, i am eager to see my question put in different words which will be more clearer

Comment: Edited your question with some example file snippet.